# How do I connect a Zebra MZ-220 printer to a Symbol MC-7095?

Tags: windows-mobile, bluetooth, driver, symbols, zebra-printers

I have a Symbol MC7095 with a windows mobile 5.0 operating system and a Zebra MZ 220 printer. Both have bluetooth. Where can I find the driver for the MZ 220 for a win 5.0 operating system? Or is there another way to connect them?

Answer (score 3):

There is a [Zebra SDK for windows-mobile devices](http://www.zebra.com/sdk)

It allows for TCP, Bluetooth, Serial (Bluetooth over serial), and USB.  There are a lot of examples on how to connect/communicate with your printer, plus convenience classes for many printer functions (file retrieval, image printing/storing, printer status, etc)

Comment: thanks for the link and answer.  I am waiting for our BT printer from Zebra but I think this is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

If it's bluetooth, then you don't need a printer-specific driver, you simply need a printer BT profile on the CE device.  If that's not there (I don't know if it is or isn't), then you'd need to inquire with Symbol/Motorola.